# "Updates were rejected" message sticks after git pull

Tags: git, gitlab

I successfully pull and merged from a repo and then I did a `git push` (cannot use `git push -f` cuz I do not have the permission) but the non-fast-forward error occurs:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@***.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This is the pull command output:

```
From ***/***
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: are you able to share the output of the pull command?

Comment: Is your project really active? If so, maybe someone just pushed to master in the time between your pull and your push.

Comment: @pixelbits updated

Comment: @zigarn and if so what will I do

Comment: Simply pull again.

Comment: Could you display the output of `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate`?

Comment: @zigarn updated

Comment: 'git branch -avv', 'git remote -vv'?

Comment: @zigarn updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147447/discussion-between-zigarn-and-aero-wang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots I can see that you somehow got into detached head state. If you perform commands like:

```
git branch tmp_head <---- watch out for "branch already exists" error here
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only tmp_head
git branch -d tmp_head
```

after that your push should succeed.

PS: the commands could be differend but I this sequence should be safer if your situation differs

Answer (score 1):

Use git pull origin master before you push anything, assume that you are using origin as a name for your remote.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this command

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```